# Zend Framework 2 - Multi Page Form

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form2

Does anyone have an example like this: [Zend Framework Multi Page Form](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.advanced.html)

But for Zend Framework 2 using Zend\Session?

Comment: Did you check the 2.2 section of the docs? http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html

Comment: Already searched google and sent email to the Zend site and nobody has any example on multi page form for ZF2. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There shouldn't be any need for such an example as this is nothing but Basics playing together:

```
public function multiFormAction()
{
    $session = $yourSessionContainer();

    if (false === $session->hasStepOneBeenDone()) {
        $form = new FormStepOne();
        // Check for Post
        // Validate Form
        // Render Form on Error or Post
        // If Valid, safe Form Data into Session
    }

    if (false === $session->hasStepTwoBeenDone()) {
        $form = new FormStepTwo();
        // Check for Post
        // Validate Form
        // Render Form on Error or Post
        // If Valid, safe Form Data into Session
    }

    if (false === $session->hasStepNBeenDone()) {
        $form = new FormStepTwo();
        // Check for Post
        // Validate Form
        // Render Form on Error or Post
        // If Valid, safe Form Data into Session
    }
}
```

All that's needed to create this is knowledge in two topics:

- [`Zend\Form`](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#zend-form)
- [`Zend\Session`](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#zend-session)

Comment: Thanks Sam. I wanted something not to be "reinventing the wheel" again. His example and others examples of ZF1 gave me some ideas. I thought of creating a controller specifically for this with Zend\Session and all.